# how to make css outline compatible in all browser?Vendor prefix aren't working [This is improper post please ignore it]

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

He guys I'm using css outline on my menu list item(li).In my chrome it works fine but in Mozilla firefox outline produce really bad result.I have used vendor prefix like :-

```
   -moz-outline:2px solid white;
   -webkit-outline:2px solid white;
```

but my mozilla shows me problem on outline :( how can i make outline property compatible for all browser?

Comment: You've used _only_ vendor prefixed rules?

Comment: Can you add complete code, jsfiddle demo showing the problem will be better

Comment: @Tushar i have used both vendor and normal without vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `outline: 2px solid white`.  No need for vendor prefixes on a CSS2 feature.

Comment: Probably just a quirk.  `outline` has been supported [for a very long time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) [[link 2](http://caniuse.com/#search=outline)].  It doesn't work for me (invalid property name), so I'm not sure how you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.className{
    outline: 2px solid white;
    -moz-outline:2px solid white;
    -webkit-outline:2px solid white;
}
```